# ioredis - handle connection retry and ECONNRESET

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis

I'm trying to handle `redis` retry connection if there's any network issue. It looks like it's working but I'm not sure because sometimes I get `ECONNRESET`.

```
redisOptions: {
        sentinels: [
            { host: process.env.redis_server_1, port: process.env.redis_port_1 },
            { host: process.env.redis_server_2, port: process.env.redis_port_2 },
            { host: process.env.redis_server_3, port: process.env.redis_port_3 },
        ],
        name: 'mymaster'
    },
```

`redisOptions` object is defined in configuration file.

```
    function updateConfigurations(){
       console.log(configuration.redisOptions);
       configuration.redisOptions.sentinelRetryStrategy = (times) => {
        console.log('Trying to connect to Redis ', times);
        return Math.min(times * 100, 10000);
       }
   //  configuration.redisOptions.retryStrategy = (times) => Math.min(times * 50, 2000);
   }
```

I'm testing this by disconnecting from VPN. The moment I disconnected from VPN, below error message is getting printed on console.

```
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20)
```

And then below logging for retry connecting

```
[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: All sentinels are unreachable. Retrying from scratch after 400ms. Last error: Connection is closed.
```

**Is this a correct way to handle retry connecting? How should I handle `ECONNRESET`?**

Comment: Found a solution for this?